# Java string replace space between two lower case string

Tags: java

How can parse/clean the string using java?

Input: "Soft ware Engi neer"

Desired Output: "Software Engineer"

I have this regex: `"([a-z])\s([a-z])"`. It can find the string `"t w"` and `"i n"`. But how do I replace the space in between the searched strings?

```
System.out.println("Soft ware Engi neer".trim().replace("([a-z])\\s([a-z])", "$1$2"));
```

Should print: `Software Engineer`

The above regex/replace works fine in Notepad++.

Comment: [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) does not handle regular expressions. Perhaps you mean [`String.replaceFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: Yep, the replaceAll works. I somehow missed that. In all my other code it does use the replaceAll. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with [a lookahead and a lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and replace spaces with an empty string:

```
System.out.println("Soft ware Engi neer".replaceAll("(?<=[a-z])\\s(?=[a-z])", ""));
```

This regex with match a single space preceded *and* followed by a lowercase character. Characters themselves are *not* included.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/3UN40h)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the method call to `replaceAll` works.

```
System.out.println("Soft ware Engi neer".trim().replaceAll("([a-z])\\s([a-z])", "$1$2"));
```